# How to change span style while hovering a div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the style of a span while hovering on a div, and this div on hover should also change its color.

This is my code so far (the bg of div changes, but the color of span doesn't, why?):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HOME</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        div{
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: red;
        }
        div:hover{
            background-color: blue;
        }
        span{
            color: blue;
        }
        div:hover span{
            color: green;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div></div>
<span>WHY</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put `span` tag inside the `div`. Something like this:

```css
div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}
div:hover{
    background-color: blue;
}
span{
    color: blue;
}
div:hover span{
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>span text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: OP had asked to change color of span text when hover on div.

Comment: I'm not saying your answer didn't solve the issue it did, but you have changed the formation of tags, before they were two individual tag and in your solution it is  parent and child.

Comment: @frnt I don't think it's a case. OP has 2 options, One for changing html tags, one for changing css. I've used the first, keep using css. Your answer may use the second.

Comment: Okay, but formation is changed. Anyways Op was indeed of solution and hopefully it solve his issue :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use + selector in CSS like following:

```
div:hover + span {
    color: green;
}
```

Here is the link of [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ray986/tr86n7vy).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JQuery. this might help you.

```
$('div').hover(function(){
  $("span").css("background-color","red");
})
```

Comment: There's no jQuery tag involved.